# Regular Expression causes errors quoted and unquoted

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm building regular expression patterns for class in Javascript.

```
    var re = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
```

This was tested on http://scriptular.com/ which claims it should work on Javascript (this is an email pattern, btw), but when used on my site it definitely does not.

Searching Google I found that putting the pattern on quotes turns it into a string, which has no .exec method explaining the 'method not found' exception I get. But then again removing the quotes gives me a lot of 'Unexpected token' exceptions.

Escaping the characters with \ seems to have no effect on the errors, so what is the correct way of doing this, then?

Here is the relevant code, if needed (uses JQuery):

```
$('#email-btn').click(function(){
    var re = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
    var t = $('#email').val();
    if (re.exec(t)) {
        console.log(t+' Works');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `re` is a string literal, you need to create [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object then [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) can be used.

```
var re = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
var regExp = new RegExp(e);
if(regExp.exec(t))
  ....
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will accept but apparently I need to wait 10 minutes.